# Estimate intersection of exponential and linear function

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms, approximation-theory

I would like to solve a function of the form $a^x = bx + c$ for $x$, but I read it can not be solved algebraically (transcendental equation).

My attempts basically fall flat at $\log_a(a^x - bx) = \log_a(c)$ as there is no way to simplify $\log_a(a^x - bx)$.

Although I did read that
$$\log(s + t) = \log(s) + \log\left(1 + \frac{t}{s}\right) \approx \log(\max(s, t))$$

So I can simplify $x \approx \log_a(a^x - bx) = \log_a(c)$, if $a^x \gg -bx$.

I tested this numerically and the results seem plausible, but I am unsure how to test if $a^x + bx$ is really large enough for the approximation to be accurate. How would I go about calculating the error to keep it below, say 1%?

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are given you can use Newton's method to find the root of $a^x - bx - c = 0$ numerically.

Comment: @prcssngnr that requires me to evaluate $a^x$ which causes a numerical overflow in my tests.. I used https://docs.rs/nrfind/latest/nrfind/fn.find_root.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use Newton's method to compute the root of $f(x) = a^x - bx - c$. Newton's method is the following algorithm:

$$ x_{n + 1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} $$

Where an initial estimate $x_0$ of the root is repeatedly improved. Substituting the relation for $f(x)$:

$$ x_{n + 1} = x_n - \frac{a^{x_n} - bx_n - c}{a^{x_n} \ln a - b} $$

We repeatedly apply the above to get better and better estimates for the root.

Comment: A problem with this approach seems to be that I need to evaluate $a^x$ which may become extremely large. I would like to avoid this, and assuming $a^x \gg -bx$ allows this because we can simplify $\log_a(a^x - bx) = \log_a(c)$ to $x \approx \log_a(c)$.

Comment: In the case where $a^x \gg -bx$ then $\log_a c$ is a reasonable estimate for the root. I did some testing and found that when $a > 50 b$ the root is close to $\log_a c$.

Comment: I did some investigating and it seems if I set $x_0$ to $\log_a(c)$, i.e. start with my previous approximation, it finds a suitable approximation very quickly and the values of $x_n$ don't grow large enough to make $a^{x_n}$ overflow. I guess this shows that its already a good approx. and I can improve it using newton's method.

Answer (score 2):

The only explicit solution of
$$a^x=bx+c \quad \implies \quad e^{x\log(a)}=bx+c $$ is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

It write
$$x=-\frac c b-\frac 1 {\log(a)}W\left(-\frac{\log (a)}{b}\, a^{-\frac{c}{b}}\right)$$ which, in the real domain, exists if
$$\frac{\log (a)}{b}\, a^{-\frac{c}{b}}~ \leq ~ \frac 1 e$$

You must take care that this is a multi-valued function (the branches being $W_0(.)$ and $W_{-1}(.)$. For example, with $(a=3,b=5,c=7)$, the solutions are close to $-1.35$ and $2.76$.

You will find in the linked page series expansion for the evaluation of this function which is more and more used.

Just by curiosity, on the search bar of the site, just type *Lambert* : you will see $4318$ entries.